# HTTP tunnel on pjsip

Tags: tunnel, pjsip

I have developed a VOIP Application, that uses PJSip to communicate over SIP channel. What i want to do is to create a HTTP tunnel so that the system works even in areas where VOIP is blocked. What is the way to achieve this using PJSip or if there is some external method then how can it be merged with PJSip??

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.  You will have to write another transport protocol in pjsip or modify the current transports to support tcp/udp over http tunneling.  There is also how you would "tunnel" the traffic through HTTP as well. You may have to make sure you are using a HTTP server that supports HTTP tunneling as well.

This may get you the SIP signalling but you may run into problems with the RTP media traffic.

You may be better off implementing TURN support into the pjsip code.  pjsip already supports TURN for RTP media so it will be less work to make it support TURN for the main SIP signalling traffic.

Altho this assumes that you can get a TURN server installed?  If you can't get a TURN server installed and your HTTP server doesn't support HTTP tunneling then you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The authorities detect about your VoIP applications by capturing your sip and RTP packets.You can tweak your pjsip and force to send all the data through one gateway(currently, pjsip opens different ports for sip/RTP/rtcp etc). You will have to change every outgoing packet also so that the authorities will not able to know that the packet is sip or RTP packet(they know the type of packet by looking at the structure of the header).
You will also need to implement a tunnel-type system through which every packet goes before going to server. This tunnel should have the capabilities of re-structuring the packets to its original state. This way you will be able to send packets to the server without being blocked.